# Could not open Selected vm debug port

Tags: android, ddms

When try to open `Android device monitor` get next error:

[image]

I tried to do:

1) Changed ports in Debugger from 63342 to 63343

2) `adb kill-server` and start `adb start-server`

Comment: Shutdown your PC and try again. It should work.

Comment: @VicJordan tried and this, doesn t help